# DirectShow: dump the stream

Tags: c++, filter, camera, windows-ce, directshow

I have some filters connection on wince device (camera -> sampleGrabber(which analyze the image ->rendering filter.

The rendering takes a lot of time, and I don't really need to see the result (only on "debugging" mode.

How can I "dump" the stream after the sampleGrabber filter?

This is the main code:

```
CHK( m_pCaptureGraphBuilder.CoCreateInstance( CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder ));
CHK( pFilterGraph.CoCreateInstance( CLSID_FilterGraph ));
CHK( m_pCaptureGraphBuilder->SetFiltergraph( pFilterGraph ));

CHK( m_pVideoCaptureFilter.CoCreateInstance( CLSID_VideoCapture ));
CHK( m_pVideoCaptureFilter.QueryInterface( &pPropertyBag ));

CHK( GetFirstCameraDriver( wzDeviceName ));
CHK( PropBag.Write( L"VCapName", &varCamName ));   
CHK( pPropertyBag->Load( &PropBag, NULL ));
// Everything succeeded, now adding the video capture filter to the filtergraph
CHK( pFilterGraph->AddFilter( m_pVideoCaptureFilter, L"Video Capture Filter Source" ));

CHK( pGrabberFilter.CoCreateInstance( CLSID_CameraGrabber ));
CHK( pFilterGraph->AddFilter( pGrabberFilter, L"Sample Grabber" ));
CHK( pGrabberFilter->QueryInterface( &m_pSampleGrabber ));

// set callback method to the grabber
m_pSampleGrabber->SetCallback(&MYCALLBACK, 0);

CHK( pVideoRenderer.CoCreateInstance( CLSID_VideoRenderer ));
CHK( pFilterGraph->AddFilter( pVideoRenderer, L"VideoMixingRenderer" ));
CHK( m_pCaptureGraphBuilder->RenderStream( &PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, &MEDIATYPE_Video, m_pVideoCaptureFilter, NULL, pVideoRenderer ));
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

To stop rendering, you can connect your sampleGrabber to the [nullRenderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which discards all the samples it receives and won't slow down your program.

If you would like to dump stream without displaying it, then you can use the [FileWriterFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375644%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: So let me understand, what's the different between both of them? It seems they both discard/ dump the samples... (or maybe there's a different between discard and dump?)

Comment: Discard means "throw it away without even processing it".  Dump means it will store somewhere in the external storage (eg. disk).

Comment: In other words, NullRenderer does nothing.  FileWriterFilter will write the stream processed by your transformation filters to a file.

Comment: Ok, so I should use NullRenderer as a sink filter, and it threw away the samples (after I precessed it and used it).

Comment: @user2004403: I have no experience on wince, but I think it should have nullRenderer as it is one of the fundamental output filters.